# Put colon delimiter between the item and definition in glossary

Tags: glossaries

How to put colon delimiter between item and definition in glossary?

Standard `glossaries` make glossary look like this:

> **item** long definition.

But I want to put some delimiter

> **item:** long definition.

Add colon to every item in `\newglossaryentry` is a very ugly solution, is there any way to define it in preamble?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The delimiter `:` can be inserted using a new glossary style, which might just be a variation of an existing one. For the standard list style, this had to be set:

```
\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
\setglossarystyle{list}% base this style on the list style
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
\item[\glsentryitem{##1}%
  \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}\myitemdelimiter}]
  \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2}
}
```

The `\glossentryname{##1}` prints the glossary short title (or acronym, perhaps), so here the delimiter has to added afterwards.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\myitemdelimiter}{:}

\newglossaryentry{Maxwell}{%
  name={James Clerk Maxwell},
  description={English physicist}
}

\newglossaryentry{Boltzmann}{%
  name={Ludwig Boltzmann},
  description={Austrian physicist}
}

\newglossaryentry{Einstein}{%
  name={Albert Einstein},
  description={German physicist}
}

\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
\setglossarystyle{list}% base this style on the list style
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
\item[\glsentryitem{##1}%
  \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}\myitemdelimiter}]
  \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2}
}


\setglossarystyle{mystyle}


\begin{document}
\glsaddall

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note** Other glossary styles need similar changes then, but this depends on the style. Please have a look on `glossaries-user.pdf`, the more elaborate of the `glossaries` manuals